# Create table with data by group

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want to creat a component Table by group contries. And this my mockup.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyd7I.png)

I don't have a solution for this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yup! but do not something

Comment: Could you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's are a couple components I found after 30 seconds of Googling:

http://vue-table-component.spatie.be

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables